# Ubuntu not loading from boot menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, os-prober

My `HP g6` laptop has dual boot installed. Windows in SSD, and Ubuntu in external SD card. I wanted Windows load by default. Therefore, I changed grub timeout to 0, and grub default to 2 (windows). And also changed `os-prober` as timeout to 0, and menu style to hidden.

Now every time PC loads to windows. I cannot load Ubuntu anymore. Though I try to select Ubuntu from boot menu (f9 at boot time), but it loads windows again. How can I be able to run Ubuntu now?

Comment: 0 is just that, no time to even make a selection. I like to use 3, but still have to be quick as default is 10. Use live installer and edit back to higher number. For first boot you may need to violate the rule of not editing /Boot/ubuntu/grub.cfg which is normally updated from /etc/default/grub.

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to get write support for your boot partition from Windows, actually changing the saved default is easy. From Windows, you can edit `/boot/grub/default`. Edit the lines that you have changed (at least the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to 1). When you restart, GRUB will read that file since your default is saved. You just have to be a little quick when the GRUB menu shows up to choose your Windows or Ubuntu.

There are several software like **Grub2Win** or other similar programs as listed [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win/files/). They provide you with an easy user interface.

Comment: Thank you so much. I already reinstalled Ubuntu in my PC. Problem therefore is solved for now. But surely your instruction will be helpful for me in the future.

Comment: Sure! If you find this answer useful in the future, you can upvote or accept this answer.